# Java Fuel-SDK searching Data Extension for Email

Tags: fuel-sdk, java, dataextensions, filters

**We are using the Java Fuel-SDK 1.0.3 to select a row with a specific email address from a Data Extension.**

The existing documentation either says ‘Coming soon!’ or points to the Javadoc.

While the Javadoc might be accurate, it is like reading the dictionary and expecting someone to speak English based on it.

The Java Fuel-SDK filter api has changed enough recently so that anything on Stackexchange is no longer correct.

**The code below correctly selects the Data Extension (Redacted to THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME) and then I attempt to filter with what I believe to be the correct approach, the response is:**

`Request parameter 'filter' could not be resolved. Exception logged`

Any suggestions are welcome, I have cowboyed many different variations.

---

**Java Code**

```
exactTargetConfiguration = new ETConfiguration();
exactTargetConfiguration.set( "clientId", clientId );
exactTargetConfiguration.set( "clientSecret", clientSecret );
ETClient exactTargetClient = new ETClient( exactTargetConfiguration );

ETResponse<ETDataExtension> response = exactTargetClient.retrieve( ETDataExtension.class,
  "'Name' = '" + preferenceCenterExternalKey + "'" );
ETDataExtension dataExtension = response.getObject();

ETFilter filter = new ETFilter();
ETExpression expression = new ETExpression();
expression.setProperty( "Email Address" );
expression.setOperator( Operator.EQUALS );
expression.setValue( email );
filter.setExpression( expression );
ETResponse<ETDataExtensionRow> dataExtensionRowSelectResponse = dataExtension.select( filter );

// Request parameter 'filter' could not be resolved. Exception logged.
```

**Full over the wire logs:**

```
2016-02-29 09:08:13,639 [http-bio-8080-exec-8]  INFO org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean  - Creating Service {http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI}PartnerAPI from WSDL: jar:file:/Users/34870/.m2/repository/fuelsdk/fuelsdk/1.0.3/fuelsdk-1.0.3.jar!/etframework.wsdl
2016-02-29 09:08:15,843 [http-bio-8080-exec-8]  INFO org.apache.cxf.services.PartnerAPI.Soap.Soap  - Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Address: https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["Retrieve"]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <fueloauth>REDACTED</fueloauth>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
        <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>Description</Properties>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
        <Properties>IsSendable</Properties>
        <Properties>IsTestable</Properties>
        <Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
          <Property>Name</Property>
          <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
          <Value>THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME</Value>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


--------------------------------------
2016-02-29 09:08:16,226 [http-bio-8080-exec-8]  INFO org.apache.cxf.services.PartnerAPI.Soap.Soap  - Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[private, max-age=0], connection=[close], Content-Length=[1676], content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Mon, 29 Feb 2016 14:07:43 GMT], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:c1e8c41f-b579-4819-8759-ac0d2e3f9e18</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:81e57bf1-7e67-452c-b2a8-a3fe53a5ec7c</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-f1a5c70f-69ab-4fe5-a62c-063b2570a8b5">
        <wsu:Created>2016-02-29T14:07:43Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2016-02-29T14:12:43Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
      <RequestID>94f02511-082b-4152-8257-d781ad4b8cd2</RequestID>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtension">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.11</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-24T14:39:36.75</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID>8a132cb6-9dd1-e511-8ec9-38eaa714273d</ObjectID>
        <CustomerKey>THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME</CustomerKey>
        <Name>THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME</Name>
        <Description>For New Preference Center Pages Not Live Yet</Description>
        <IsSendable>false</IsSendable>
        <IsTestable>false</IsTestable>
        <CategoryID>44172</CategoryID>
      </Results>
    </RetrieveResponseMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


--------------------------------------
2016-02-29 09:08:16,405 [http-bio-8080-exec-8]  INFO org.apache.cxf.services.PartnerAPI.Soap.Soap  - Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 2
Address: https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["Retrieve"]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <fueloauth>REDACTED</fueloauth>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>FieldType</Properties>
        <Properties>DefaultValue</Properties>
        <Properties>IsPrimaryKey</Properties>
        <Properties>IsRequired</Properties>
        <Properties>MaxLength</Properties>
        <Properties>Scale</Properties>
        <Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
          <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
          <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
          <Value>THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME</Value>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


--------------------------------------


2016-02-29 09:08:17,067 [http-bio-8080-exec-8]  INFO org.apache.cxf.services.PartnerAPI.Soap.Soap  - Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 2
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[private, max-age=0], connection=[close], Content-Length=[14577], content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Mon, 29 Feb 2016 14:07:43 GMT], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:4c0e3b1d-1dcf-499f-acc2-6052042c8f69</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:f228c39a-a384-44ba-bc83-c38443945a98</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6ebcafe8-42d9-4148-a133-54ec515a7f67">
        <wsu:Created>2016-02-29T14:07:44Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2016-02-29T14:12:44Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
      <RequestID>57e652d3-74dd-483a-8ed7-34559742032f</RequestID>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.853</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.297</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Coupon redemption flag]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Coupon redemption flag</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:09.787</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:09.787</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Active status date]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Active status date</Name>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.88</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.303</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Coupon redemption date]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Coupon redemption date</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.253</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.16</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Last Name]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Last Name</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.753</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.27</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Email opt-in flag]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Email opt-in flag</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.637</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.253</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[IP Address]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>IP Address</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>30</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.71</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.27</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Mobile opt-in flag]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Mobile opt-in flag</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.69</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.267</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Profile complete flag]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Profile complete flag</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.79</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.28</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Email opt-in date]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Email opt-in date</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.557</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.237</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Mobile Number]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Mobile Number</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>50</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.333</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.207</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[City]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>City</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>50</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.643</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.257</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Original Source]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Original Source</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>50</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.423</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.22</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Postal Code-ZIP]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Postal Code-ZIP</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>20</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:09.773</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:09.773</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Active status flag]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Active status flag</Name>
        <DefaultValue>true</DefaultValue>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.833</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.29</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Coupon sent date]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Coupon sent date</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.68</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.267</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[A List member flag]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>A List member flag</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.57</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.57</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[ET_Create_Date]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>ET_Create_Date</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue>GetDate()</DefaultValue>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.67</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.257</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Email Frequency]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Email Frequency</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>30</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.27</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.163</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Date of Birth]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Date of Birth</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.3</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.177</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Address]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Address</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.317</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.2</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Address 2]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Address 2</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.47</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.223</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Country]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Country</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>2</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.48</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.23</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Language]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Language</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>2</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.13</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.123</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Email Address]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Email Address</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>254</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>true</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.293</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.173</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Gender]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Gender</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>1</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.193</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.16</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[First Name]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>First Name</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.8</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.287</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Coupon sent flag]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Coupon sent flag</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue>false</DefaultValue>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.577</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.247</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[ET_Last_Modified_Date]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>ET_Last_Modified_Date</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.72</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.27</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Mobile opt-in date]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Mobile opt-in date</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
      </Results>
      <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionField">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CreatedDate>2016-02-12T09:31:42.347</CreatedDate>
        <ModifiedDate>2016-02-12T11:16:06.213</ModifiedDate>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>[THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME].[Province-State]</CustomerKey>
        <Name>Province-State</Name>
        <Scale>0</Scale>
        <DefaultValue/>
        <MaxLength>30</MaxLength>
        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
        <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
      </Results>
    </RetrieveResponseMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


--------------------------------------


2016-02-29 09:08:17,237 [http-bio-8080-exec-8]  INFO org.apache.cxf.services.PartnerAPI.Soap.Soap  - Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 3
Address: https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["Create"]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <fueloauth>REDACTED</fueloauth>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
      <Options/>
      <Objects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="AudienceBuilderRestCall">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <URL>customobjectdata/key/{key}/rowset</URL>
        <Method>GET</Method>
        <Parameters>
          <Name>$filter</Name>
          <Value>Email Address eq gturner@olson.com</Value>
        </Parameters>
        <Parameters>
          <Name>$fields</Name>
          <Value>coupon redemption flag,active status date,coupon redemption date,last name,email opt-in flag,ip address,mobile opt-in flag,profile complete flag,email opt-in date,mobile number,city,original source,postal code-zip,active status flag,coupon sent date,a list member flag,et_create_date,email frequency,date of birth,address,address 2,country,language,email address,gender,first name,coupon sent flag,et_last_modified_date,mobile opt-in date,province-state</Value>
        </Parameters>
        <Parameters>
          <Name>key</Name>
          <Value>THE_DATA_EXTENSION_NAME</Value>
        </Parameters>
      </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


--------------------------------------
2016-02-29 09:08:19,145 [http-bio-8080-exec-8]  INFO org.apache.cxf.services.PartnerAPI.Soap.Soap  - Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 3
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[private, max-age=0], connection=[close], Content-Length=[1369], content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Mon, 29 Feb 2016 14:07:46 GMT], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:085bf78f-5e97-4502-b54f-20891e060414</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:f3a386d9-e941-4b42-9788-3a75f3aa9143</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-7f9d1436-365f-45ff-b486-5e4870a688a8">
        <wsu:Created>2016-02-29T14:07:46Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2016-02-29T14:12:46Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Results>
        <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
        <StatusMessage>Request parameter 'filter' could not be resolved. Exception logged.</StatusMessage>
        <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
        <NewID>0</NewID>
      </Results>
      <RequestID>e2a517fe-f9aa-4427-a296-4e3231eecb5e</RequestID>
      <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
    </CreateResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is that for v1.0.3 the Data Extension filtering is **NOT** working.

I did a build from the Github repo, commit [d83684689278a0bb73e699566f3938a453fd01e8](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java/commit/d83684689278a0bb73e699566f3938a453fd01e8), and the above code appeared to work as expected.